# Ubuntu Visual Studio Code Toggle Comment no respond

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-16.04

I encountered an issue with toggle comment in visual studio code on Ubuntu. Default hot key was "ctrl+/", it didn't respond when I click on a line of code or highlighted the line of code. I changed the hot key to "ctrl+l" under preference -> Keyboard Shortcuts and it didn't respond too.

I tried to google this but nobody seems to encounter this issue or posted this question.

Is there something else I need to enable to make this work?

Comment: Did you try to disable all extensions before using shortcut?

Comment: do you mean the keymap extensions? or the extensions under settings like "extensions update", "extensions.ignoreRecommendations" and "emmet.extensionsPath"? Those in settings I left it as default. The ones in keymap extensions were all not installed.

Comment: I mean all extensions maybe there is a conflict with it

Comment: I tried toggling  "extensions update", "extensions.ignoreRecommendations" and "emmet.extensionsPath" but still no respond for toggle comment.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was due to the fact that VS Code 'didn't know' the language the file was written in. I was editing a .cmake file and VS Code does not 'understand' CMake syntax when installed out-of-the-box.

Installing a 'CMake' extension enabling CMake syntax highlight also enabled the 'Toggle Line Comment' [Ctrl+/] shortcut to work.

(I'm guessing without the specified language VS Code simply does not know which symbol to use to comment out the lines - e.g. '//' or '#' or else).

Answer (score 1):

This the issue because in ctrl + /
/ -> is numpad divide
or
/-> simple / the key not present in numpad
so if you try any of these combinations one will definitely work, if u want to work with numpad one only you can go to
File-> Preferences -> Keyboard shortcuts (there search for toggle line comment and give your own shortcut)

Answer (score 0):

For me, in VSCode has a error with `ctrl + }` and `ctrl + shift + }` 'cause is inversly and no show correctly the keys to hit.

You must redirect to Keyboard Shortcuts - Visual Studio Code, and search the shortcut "Comment", and hit:

`blockComment`: Insert `ctrl + }` when you hit `ctrl + shift + }`.

`commentLine`: Insert `ctrl + shift + }` when you hit `ctrl + }`.

[The Shortcuts show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmv26.png)

I hope that help for you.

Answer (score 0):

That how I solved it. Open File/Preferences/Keyboard Shortcuts or type ctrl+K ctrl+S [VSCode preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq86Z.png). Then click {} button in the top-right corner. In the last version on Sep 16, 2019, it looks like a file with the arrow. Now you see keybindings.json, at the bottom there is a button Define keybindings - click and type in the form there "Ctrl+/" It will show you all commands with your combination. I found and commented the one from Emmet

```
`  {
        "key": "ctrl+/",
        "command": "editor.emmet.action.toggleComment",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },`
```

There was a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I didn' found the answer in the internet, but eventually I found it on my own.

My system is Linux Mint and my computer is a Thinkpad 440p with an brazilian Portuguese keyboard. This keyboard doesn't have a Right Control key, and then key usually associated with it is used for slash (/) and interrogation mark if pressed with shift. Mint has a good driver for it, mapping it to the correct symbol. I have never had issue with any other code editor or software.

However VSCode by default bypass this keymap done by the system and uses raw code com from keyboard hardware. This can be changed in setting, keyboard dispatch. I change it from "code" to "keymap" and then it worked like a charm.